# restriction on properties of Realm Model

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have this model

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface RGGoal : RLMObject

@property NSString *title;
@property NSNumber *totalTime;
@property NSNumber *noMileStones;
@property NSString *goalDescription;
```

I setup breaking points and figured that when `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];` is called the app terminates with following

> 'RLMException' exception: Property of type `NSNumber` must descend from RLMObject

Does anyone now how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using NSNumber as type for your properties. Realm doesn't support that as NSNumber can be any numeric value (bool, integer, double, etc.). You must use types like int, float, double, etc. Please take a look at http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.81.0/api/Classes/RLMObject.html.

Comment: Why didn't you mention it in this link http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.83.0/ . This is a serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.96.0, optional numbers can be stored using an NSNumber * property which is tagged with the type of the number. 
You can use NSNumber *, NSNumber *, NSNumber *, and NSNumber *.

Please check https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.96.0/